# How to use __repr__ to create new object from it?

Tags: python, repr

This is something I don't really get. I am trying to use `__repr__` to create a new object from its output.

I have a class, OrderedSet, which contains a list and methods to organize it.
The **str** method of this class is

```
def __str__(self):
    s = "Set contains: "
    for elem in self.list: s += (" '" + elem + "'")
    return s
```

Now I am supposed to use `__repr__` in a way to instanciate a new object from it.
Like `Orderedset second = repr(first)`

Can I just do it like this?

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.list.__str__()
```

Comment: With `eval(repr(some_object))`? See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13229289/1639625).

Comment: As a side note: `list` is a bad variable name since there is a builtin function of the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind "using `__repr__` to create new objects" is that the output of `__repr__` [can be valid python code](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), which, when interpreted with `eval`, creates (a copy of) the original object. For example, `repr("foo")` return `"'foo'"` (including the quotes), or `repr([1,2,3])` returns `'[1, 2, 3]'`.

In your example you probably need something like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "OrderedSet(%r)" % self.list
```

as well as a corresponding constructor:

```
def __init__(self, elements):
    self.list = elements
```

This way, `repr(OrderedSet([1,2,3]))` returns the string `OrderedSet([1,2,3])`, which, when `eval`uated, will invoke the contructor and create a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 4):

No. `__repr__()` has to return a string or a lot of code would break.

Try this approach: `__repr__()` should return valid Python code. That would allow you to

```
second = eval(repr(first))
```

That said, the whole idea looks dubious. It feels like you try to come up with a clever way to serialize or clone objects.

Use [pickling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) for serialization or maybe the `json` module. To clone, use a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Copy_constructors).